# Find non-matching Excel values

Tags: excel

I have a column of values in Excel like this:

```
T0426-ZS-104
T0470-SV-127
T0427-ZS-109
T0423-ZS-110
T0426-SV-133
T0426-ZS-128
T0426-ZS-109
T0426-ZS-144
T0426-ZS-133
T0427-SV-109
T0426-SV-210
T0470-ZS-127
T0430-ZS-196
T0426-SV-104
T0430-SV-196
```

Some of the values have a matching "SV" and "ZS" part (e.g. T0426-SV-104 and T0426-ZS-104).

Others don't have a matching value, such as T0423-ZS-110, T0426-ZS-144 AND T0426-SV-210. How can I isolate all the non-matching values and place them in another column?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: I am trying to match..the first and third parts of each three-part value

Comment: Next time you post please clearly describe your problem so that other users don't spend time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Formula in `B1` downwards:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"ZS","*"),"SV","*")
```

Formula in `C1` downwards:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)
```

Formula in `D1` downwards:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"ZS","*"),"SV","*"))=1,A1,"")
```

The formulas in column `B`and `C` are only to show the principle. Those columns are not needed as helper columns.